# Trouble with XPath

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, roblox

I'm trying to modify a program for automatic roblox account generation because there is a captcha (that doesn't occur every single time) that messes up the generation process and I want to use XPath to detect the different captcha and close out of the webdriver window. Here is the original program on github: https://github.com/Imagine-YT/Roblox-Account-Generator

here is the version im modifying: https://github.com/HoodedPeak8313/roblox-account-gen

line 181 is where im having trouble

im trying to detect the button because the two captchas have different text values

the weird-captcha's text value is "Start Puzzle" and the normal captcha's value is "Verify"
the weird captcha has no ID and the class changes each time so xpath or text would be the best way

(I am 14 and am new to python but have some experience so please bear with me if I have trouble understanding)

I tried to modify the program (around line 181), expected that the webdriver window would close upon detecting the weird-captcha and do nothing when it detects the normal captcha. what happened is that the window closed every time no matter what without printing anything to the console window (not even NoSuchElementExcpetion was detected)

Comment: If the company provides an API for account generation, obtain a key and use the API.  If the company does not provide an API, and they place account generation behind security measures to prevent automated access, take the hint.  Use your time and talent to build something great without dependence on a system that does not want you there in that way.